# I thought of installing Linux on my Xbox 360 through Ubuntu. Is it possible to play and mod a game like Skyrim on it

Tags: games

I just want to know if it is possible to play games like Skyrim on Xbox 360 linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)